# How is energy released when a chemical bond is formed?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, bond

Chemical reactions are classed as endothermic or exothermic.

Defn: exothermic

> (of a reaction or process) accompanied by the release of heat.

The heat is released when the chemical bonds in the product are formed.

Defn: heat

> heat is energy in transfer to or from a thermodynamic system, ... The
>   mechanisms include conduction, ...; or radiation between separated
>   bodies; or ....

So, I have three questions:

1 - if the heat is released via conduction, is this equivalent to an increase in the kinetic energy of the product(s) compared to the kinetic energy of the reactant(s)?  Also, how does the formation of a chemical bond produce kinetic energy?

2 - if the heat is released via radiation, how is radiation created in the formation of a chemical bond?

3 - are conduction and radiation the only forms of heat transfer when a bond is created?

Edit - to clarify the question - the issue is addresed in the OPENSTAX AP chemistry text - which covers one example of 2 H atoms coming together to form H2 in detail as follows:

> When the atoms are far apart ..... by convention the sum of their
>   energies is 0. As the atoms move together their orbitals begin to
>   overlap.  Each electron begins to feel the attraction of the nucleus in
>   the other atom.  In addition, the electrons begin to repel each other,
>   as do the nuclei.  While the atoms are still separated, the
>   attractions are slightly stronger than the repulsions, and the energy
>   of the system decreases. (A bond begins to form.) ... At some specific
>   distance between the atoms, which varies with the atoms involved, the
>   energy reaches its lowest  (most stable) value.  This optimum distance
>   between the two bonded nuclei is the bond distance between the two
>   atoms.

The text doesn't specify what energy is decreasing, and why.  But I can answer these questions I think.  The energy that is decreasing is the potential energies of the attractive fields of the atoms, and that energy is being transformed to kinetic energy as the atoms accelerate toward each other.

So we have the nuclei accelerating towards each other.  What happens next?

According to the text ... continuing where we left off

> The bond is stable because at this point the attractive and repulsive
>   forces combine to create the lowest possible energy configuration.

So there is no mention of the release of energy, and the atoms just arrive at the stable combined state.

Here is what I would expect, given that the nuclei are accelerating towards each other - at some point the repulsive forces become stronger than the attractive forces, and the atoms begin to decelerate.  If there is no damping force on the motion the atoms will oscillate about the point where the attractive and repulsive forces are equal.  So, there must be some damping force on the atoms, that causes them to come rest at the bond distance of H2.

Now comes the mystery, which is, how does the formation of a chemical bond release energy?

What happens to the kinetic energy of the two nuclei accelerating towards each other?  If the two hydrogen atoms are coming together head on there will be a collision that would appear to cancel out the motion, i.e. kinetic energy, of both atoms.  If there is a damping mechanism that generates the heat, what is it?

Since the energy is released as heat, I think it must be in the form of kinetic or electromagnetic energy, but what is the specific mechanism?

Or, am I trying to get too much out of the kinetic model?

Comment: Further, the subject is covered in my high school kid's chemistry text, OPENSTAX Chemistry, in the chapter 'Chemical Bonding and Molecular Geometry' as follows: 'plus the energy released when all bonds are formed', and 'the excess energy is released as heat', and that's it.

Comment: I think the issue is that you ask a couple different subquestions and any one of these has the potential to turn into a long answer depending on how much you know and how much detail you want. I think the overall question is interesting and it got a good, so I'll vote to reopen, but I think a full answer to the question could  cover excited states, various types of radiative and non radiative transitions, how collisions exchange energy between a system and its environment, and so on.

Comment: This is very ill-posed question. How heat can be transferred macroscopically has little to do with molecular process of bond formation. Heat can be also transferred via convection, but what it has to do with single molecule being formed?

Comment: @Tyberius - I'm not looking for a full treatment, just one simple example would do, suitable for a high school class.  To that end I've edited the question with an example from a high school text that describes the formation of a bond, but leaves out the part about the release of energy.

Comment: Also, the college board has an article, 'Ending Misconceptions About the Energy of Chemical Bonds', link: https://apcentral.collegeboard.org/courses/ap-chemistry/classroom-resources/ending-misconceptions-about-energy-chemical-bonds  which does not answer the question.

Comment: Rather than deleting the question (which we will not do because it is answered) and asking it anew, it is preferable to [edit] the question for clarity. Now this is a bit of a problem here, as the question is already answered. In such cases it would be best to ask a new question as a follow-up to this question. When in doubt, please consult [meta] to ask for advice.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/55914/how-is-heat-physically-released-in-an-exothermic-process

Answer (score 4):

It is easier first to think of what happens when a bond is broken in an exothermic reaction. The energy is initially released into vibrations,  rotations and translational motion of the two fragments. This energy is then lost as these fragments collide with other gas molecules or with solvent molecules and so eventually ends up as heat.

In exothermic bond formation the extra energy vibrationally and rotationally excites the new molecule and this is then lost via collisions with surrounding gas or solvent molecules and again ends up as heat.

(If the new molecule were isolated in space (so no collisions) it would remain 'hot' until the energy is radiated away from vibrational levels and until it (radiatively) comes into equilibrium with the surroundings. This is a  slow process, by many orders of magnitude,  compared to collisions in solution or in a gas at normal atmospheric pressure )

In a very few types of reaction an electronically excited state is produced in the product and then photons radiate (as visible light) some of the energy away. This is called chemiluminescence.

Comment: Energy is not released when a bond is broken.  It requires energy to break a bond.

Comment: The question is about an exothermic reaction in which case energy is released

Comment: Still, energy is not released when a bond is broken, even in an exothermic reaction.

You need to separate two atoms which have an attractive force between them. That *has to require* energy. 

In an exothermic reaction, *generally*, more bonds form than break, so there is an energy surplus.

Comment: You are not quite correct. You are effectively talking about the activation energy, or energy barrier, between reactant and product,  when this is surmounted more energy is released in an exothermic reaction than needed to overcome the barrier.

Comment: Energy is never released when a bond is broken in isolation. An exothermic reaction involves stronger bonds forming than are broken, it is the formation that releases the energy. Activation energy doesn’t affect this as it only involves the energy that must be overcome during the reaction pathway, not the potential energies of the bonding states before and after.

Comment: No, you are wrong.

Comment: Not to reopen an old argument, but @Withnail was right (i.e. you spend energy breaking bonds and get energy back when bonds form, thus an exothermic reaction means you spent more energy breaking reactives than got back from forming products). You have evidence for it in this FAQ: https://www.studysmarter.us/explanations/chemistry/physical-chemistry/bond-enthalpy/ and in these questions/answers: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/is-there-an-example-of-a-bond-with-negative-bond-enthalpy?newreg=c0e74d4a0caf4cfd94f1f1f5a058651d and https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/13583

Comment: @Rusca8 If you just break a bond say $\ce{H_2\to H\cdot  + H\cdot}$  of course this needs energy but in a reaction say $\ce{F + H2 \to HF + H}$ then this is exothermic and the HF product is rotationally, vibrationally and translationally excited to account for  the $130$ kJ/mole energy released. In fact so much vibrational energy is available in the HF product  that this can be made into an infra red laser.

Comment: But the point was (for all of them) that the reaction is exothermic cause you're getting more energy from creating HF than you spend breaking H2. Specifically, your 130kJ/mol are there because you're getting 565 kJ/mol from forming HF and spending 432 kJ/mol on breaking H2. So the breaking of a bond is indeed always endothermic. It's just that the product you're forming releases more energy than the energy you spent.

Comment: yes of course, the question was ' how is energy released...' which I think I have answered.